# React table how to show 3 items each row using map loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Using material UI table, my current table generates one column on each row. I'd like to show 3 columns as items on each row, below is my table map:

```
<TableBody>
    {this.props.data.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage).map(n => {

        return (
            <TableRow key={n.id}>
                <TableCell>
                {n.title}
                </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
        );
    })}
</TableBody>
```

so result should show: `<tr><td>data1</td><td>data2</td><td>data3</td><tr>` instead of this `<tr><td>data1</td><tr>`

Comment: Are you using material-ui@next or v0?

Comment: material-ui@next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested but you could pre-process your data, grouping it into
`[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]`, etc and map over the inner triplets.

```
{this.props.data
   .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
   .reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
     // Every 3rd element, flush currGrp and append it to groupedData
     if (i > 0 && i % 3 === 0) {
       return {currGrp:[curr], groupedData: [...groupedData, acc.currGrp]}
     }
     return {currGrp: [...acc.currGrp, curr], groupedData: acc.groupedData }
   }, {currGrp: [], groupedData: []})
   .groupedData
   .map(group => 
      <TableRow key={n.id}>
        {group.map(g => 
          <TableCell>
            {g.title}
          </TableCell>
        )}
      </TableRow>
    )}
}
```